# Greatest Hit questions data/route in API

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

Can we get access to the [greatest hits](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/) functionality of the websites?

Something like /questions/hits, and with an id (as in user ID) parameter to match the website.

Maybe in version 2.1? This data would be great for the first view of a user section.